# JQuery: mouseout event triggering

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I am trying to simulate event handling on mouseout using jQuery, however the event handler is not invoked in the test environment. What might be the cause?

Comment: post your code to http://jsfiddle.net/.
I'd like to mess around with your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test, .comments').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $('.comments').stop(true,true).show('slow');
    });
    $('#test').on('mouseleave', function() {
        $('.comments').stop(true,true).hide('slow');
    });
})​;​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9zQPm/)

Could also be shortened to just:

```
$('#test').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('.comments').stop(true,true)[e.type==='mouseenter'?'show':'hide']('slow');
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9zQPm/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for mouseenter and mouseleave.

They execute only once on hover and on out.

http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/